# A question in the equations of Christoffel symbols

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $S$ be a regular and orientable surface and $p \in S$. Let $(U , \varphi)$ ($\varphi : U \to S$) be a chart in $S$, with $p \in \varphi(U) \subset S$, such that $(u_1 , u_2)$ are canonical coordinates in $U$. If I consider the Gauss application of $S$, $\mathcal{N} : S \to {\mathbb{R}}^3$, we can obtain that
$$
\{{\varphi}_{u_1}(q) , {\varphi}_{u_2}(q) , \mathcal{N}(p)\}
$$
is a base for ${\mathbb{R}}^3$, where ${\varphi}_{u_i}(q) = d {\varphi}_q(e_i)$ ($d {\varphi}_q$ is the differential of $\varphi$ evaluated in $q$, $e_1 = {(1 , 0 , 0)}^t$ and $e_2 = {(0 , 1 , 0)}^t$), being $q = {\varphi}^{- 1}(p)$. So exist two finite sequences of functions, ${\{{\Gamma}_{i , j}^k\}}_{i , j , k = 1}^2$ and ${\{L_{i , j}\}}_{i , j = 1}^2$, definited in $\varphi(U)$ to $\mathbb{R}$, such that
$$
{\varphi}_{u_i u_j}(q) = \sum_{k = 1}^2 {\Gamma}_{i , j}^k(q) {\varphi}_{u_k}(q) + L_{i , j}(q) \mathcal{N}(p) \quad \mbox{ for each } \quad i , j = 1 , 2 \tag{1}\mbox{,}
$$
being ${\Gamma}_{i , j}^k$ the called Christoffel symbols. My question is: under this context, how can I prove that
$$
L_{1 , 1}(q) = e(q) \mbox{, } \quad L_{1 , 2}(q) = L_{2 , 1}(q) = f(q) \quad \mbox{ and } \quad L_{2 , 2} = g(q)\mbox{,}
$$
being $e , f$ and $g$ the coefficients of the second fundamental form? In the page 236 of Differential Geometry of curves and surfaces (Do Carmo) says that I must do the product of $(1)$ with $\mathcal{N}(p)$ to obtain these four equalities but I haven't obtain any result. Thank you very much.

Comment: First, $e_1=(1,0)^t$, not $(1,0,0)^t$, as $U\subset\Bbb R^2$. But the *definition* of $e(q)$ is precisely $L_{1,1}\cdot\cal N$, etc. So if you take the inner product of (1) [say, with $i=j=1$] with $\cal N$, you get precisely that.